# Set different Calculation in each Input Type="number" with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Now im doing PHP code combine with JQuery for calculation. Im not so experience with JQuery. i explain with this image

[image]

I have 3 Fields : "capital", "markup", and "Cost Per Item". each of this field have different formula. The formula is to calculate each of the field.

here is the formula :

- Capital = Cost_Per_Item / ( (100 + Markup ) / 100 )
- Markup = (( Cost_Per_Item / Capital ) - 1 ) * 100
- Cost_Per_Item = ( Capital + ( Capital * ( Markup / 100 )))

in this case, im trying to build with JQuery for set up the formula. Here is what i've did. i also make a sample here https://repl.it/@ferdinandgush/3-formula . just click "Run" button on the top page and you able to test it.

HTML

```js
$(function() {
  $('.capital').on('input', function() {
    var capital = $(this).val();
    var markup = $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val();
    var costPerUnit = $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val();

    if (markup != '') {
      var formulaCostPerunit = (capital + (capital * (markup / 100)));
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val(formulaCostPerunit);
    }

    if (costPerUnit != '') {
      var formulaMarkup = ((costPerUnit / capital) - 1) * 100;
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val(formulaMarkup);
    }
  });

  $('.markup').on('input', function() {

    var capital = $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val();
    var markup = $(this).val();
    var costPerUnit = $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val();

    if (capital != '') {
      var formulaCostPerunit = (capital + (capital * (markup / 100)));
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val(formulaCostPerunit);
    }

    if (costPerUnit != '') {
      var formulaCapital = costPerUnit / ((100 + markup) / 100)
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val(formulaCapital);
    }
  });

  $('.costPerUnit').on('input', function() {

    var capital = $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val();
    var markup = $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val();
    var costPerUnit = $(this).val();

    if (capital != '') {
      var formulaMarkup = ((costPerUnit / capital) - 1) * 100;
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val(formulaMarkup);
    }

    if (markup != '') {
      var formulaCapital = costPerUnit / ((100 + markup) / 100)
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val(formulaCapital);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-6hok">ITEM</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">CAPITAL</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">MARKUP (%)</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">COST PER ITEM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="capital" name="capital[12][0]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="markup" name="markup[12][0]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="costPerUnit" name="cost_per_unit[12][0]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="capital" name="capital[12][1]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="markup" name="markup[12][1]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="costPerUnit" name="cost_per_unit[12][1]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This JQuery is still error to implement. How do i can resolve this. please help.

Comment: Why put the executable version at repl.it? You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make an executable example here.

Comment: ah sorry, im new on stackoverflow.. will learn it. thank you for your reply

Comment: Pointless to duplicate all that code when you could have one event handler for events on both sets of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the other fields are filled in when you edit the third field, your code will recalculate each of the other fields.

For instance, if both capital and cost per item are filled in, and you then edit markup, it will calculate a new cost per item from the original capital and the edited markup, and a new capital from the original cost per item and the edited markup.

You need to choose one to have priority, and only update one of the other two fields. You can use `else if` instead of the second `if` so it doesn't do both updates.

Another problem is that you're not converting the inputs to numbers before doing your calculations. As a result, `+` is performing concatenation instead of addition.

If the user edits the input field to an empty value, you should treat that as a default value.

You can use `toFixed(2)` to display the results using just 2 digits after the decimal point, rather than long fractions.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.capital').on('input', function() {
    var capital = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
    var markup = $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val();
    var costPerUnit = $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val();

    if (markup != '') {
      markup = parseFloat(markup);
      var formulaCostPerunit = (capital + (capital * (markup / 100)));
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val(formulaCostPerunit.toFixed(2));
    } else if (costPerUnit != '') {
      costPerUnit = parseFloat(costPerUnit);
      var formulaMarkup = ((costPerUnit / capital) - 1) * 100;
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val(formulaMarkup.toFixed(2));
    }
  });

  $('.markup').on('input', function() {
    var capital = $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val();
    var markup = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
    var costPerUnit = $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val();

    if (capital != '') {
      capital = parseFloat(capital);
      var formulaCostPerunit = (capital + (capital * (markup / 100)));
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.costPerUnit').val(formulaCostPerunit.toFixed(2));
    } else if (costPerUnit != '') {
      costPerUnit = parseFloat(costPerUnit);
      var formulaCapital = costPerUnit / ((100 + markup) / 100)
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val(formulaCapital.toFixed(2));
    }
  });

  $('.costPerUnit').on('input', function() {
    var capital = $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val();
    var markup = $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val();
    var costPerUnit = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);

    if (capital != '') {
      capital = parseFloat(capital);
      var formulaMarkup = ((costPerUnit / capital) - 1) * 100;
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.markup').val(formulaMarkup.toFixed(2));
    } else if (markup != '') {
      markup = parseFloat(markup);
      var formulaCapital = costPerUnit / ((100 + markup) / 100)
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.capital').val(formulaCapital.toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-6hok">ITEM</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">CAPITAL</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">MARKUP (%)</th>
      <th class="tg-6hok">COST PER ITEM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="capital" name="capital[12][0]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="markup" name="markup[12][0]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="costPerUnit" name="cost_per_unit[12][0]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="capital" name="capital[12][1]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="markup" name="markup[12][1]"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="number" class="costPerUnit" name="cost_per_unit[12][1]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```